# Insert variable into powershell string block in powershell

Tags: powershell

How would I insert variables in the html code i have stored in the variables?  What I try it with a $ in the front, it does not detect it.  I may be going about this all wrong so any tips are greatly appreciated.

```
    $myvariable = "string"

$header = 
@"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <title>System Report</title>
    <style>
    body {
        padding-top: 50px;
      }
      .starter-template {
        padding: 40px 15px;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
"@
$myevents = Get-EventLog -EntryType error -LogName application -Newest 25| Select-Object eventid,message,TimeGenerated


$myevents | ConvertTo-Html -Head $header -PreContent $body -PostContent $endhtml -CssUri C:\powershell\bootstrap.css > testing.html
    invoke-item testing.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside whatever HTML tag you want to add your value, you can include it as `$($myvariable)`.

Ex.

```
<body>$($myvariable)</body>
```